# Uninstalled game, now LAN onboard NIC not turning on

Tags: windows-7, networking, drivers, gaming, wired-networking

I am dealing with an older PC with Windows 7 and I have uninstalled the game League of Legends by Riot and Tencent games. Then when I rebooted my PC I could not get the ethernet jack to turn on. After troubleshooting the network and sharing center options, and reinstalling drivers, it would not work or even show up as a device in Device Manager. It is still there somewhere in Windows though because I can find it in the registry, and adding the driver as an extra driver will add a copy of the device with a "#2" in the name, but that doesn't fix it.
I have tried restarting, pulling the power plug, pulling the CAT cable, nothing works. 
Strangely, reinstalling the game fixes the problem, but I cancelled it because I do not play it anymore.

Comment: I know you've tried reinstalling the drivers, but have you gone into device manager and completely uninstalled the drivers, then try reinstalling? I would reinstall the game and download the driver onto a flash drive or something instead of using the Windows recommended install.